# Qemu Windows VM bluescreens launching Just Cause 3

Tags: windows-10, bsod, nvidia-graphics-card, qemu, display-driver

Now this is quite specfic, and I'm sorry about that.

I am running a Windows 10 virtual machine using QEMU inside my physical Arch Linux install. The virtual machine is set up with GPU passthrough. It uses the VFIO BIOS.

When launching Just Cause 3 through Steam (the one other thread on the internet with this issue says this is also the case for other Avalanche games, e.g. Mad Max), Windows instantly bluescreens at ntoskrnl.exe. Other games do not have this issue and run without any issue. Just Cause 3 worked without an issue on the same hardware on a physical, dedicated Windows install.

Graphics drivers are completely up to date, and fast boot is off (apparently this can cause issues).

I don't really expect an exact solution (as I said, this is quite specific), but if anybody can at least *suggest* things to try, I'd be grateful. I have attached the dump and my hardware as images:

[Blue screen dump](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cUSxv.png)

[Speccy hardware](https://i.stack.imgur.com/snDEt.png)

Comment: share the real dmp, not this useless picture. 0x3B crashes can be graphic driver issues: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff558949(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Apologies, I probably should have done this. I also really should have come back here once I solved it. I'll add an answer now.

Answer (score 1):

It took me hours of searching Google to find *anybody* who had the same issue as me. I eventually found [this Reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/VFIO/comments/42dj7n/some_games_crash_to_biosboot_on_launch/) which also explained the reason and gave a fix:

"Most likely the VM trying to access an unsupported MSR. You can check if this is the error by running `dmesg -wH` and observing the output upon the crash. Adding `echo 1 > /sys/module/kvm/parameters/ignore_msrs` to the top of your startup script should fix the issue."

This fixed the problem instantly.

Sorry for the poorly worded question (I also should have mentioned I was using VFIO).